# why is elif not working in my example in Python?

Tags: python, if-statement

I've read several other questions about this subject and my identation seems correct, I really dont understand why the code below is not working!

```
import datetime
def validate(date_text):
  if datetime.datetime.strptime(date_text, '%Y-%m-%d'):
    print('format is YMD')
  elif datetime.datetime.strptime(date_text, '%Y-%d-%m'):
    print('format is YDM')
  elif datetime.datetime.strptime(date_text, '%d-%m-%Y'):
    print('format is DMY')
  elif datetime.datetime.strptime(date_text, '%m-%d-%Y'):
    print('format is MDY')
  else:
    print('other')

validate('2003-12-23')
```

This works...

```
validate('2003-23-12')
```

This does not work! i get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-45-d6fe5c34e65c> in <module>()
----> 1 validate('2003-23-12')

2 frames

/usr/lib/python3.7/_strptime.py in _strptime(data_string, format)
    357     if not found:
    358         raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
--> 359                          (data_string, format))
    360     if len(data_string) != found.end():
    361         raise ValueError("unconverted data remains: %s" %

ValueError: time data '2003-23-12' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'
```

Thank you in advane for your help, I really don't understand why it does not work! my identations seem correct.

Comment: When `strptime` fails, it doesn't return a *falsey* value, it *raises an exception*, which prevents any further code from executing, unless you catch it with `try..except ValueError`…

Comment: aaah I see what you mean thank you!

Comment: Note that this code is fundamentally broken, anyway - 1/3 of the time, the day number is in the valid range for months, so you cannot possibly distinguish between YMD and YDM.

Comment: yes i was aware of this thank you

Answer (score -2):

It is because you are sending in 23 for the month. Maybe just catch the error and return false.